# I am trying to start mongoDB server using the command mongod. However I get the following error

Tags: mongodb

This is the error that I get on issuing `mongod` in the terminal

```
2017-06-25T14:53:50.591+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB 
starting : pid=7402 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit 
host=bhagyashree-MS-7994
2017-06-25T14:53:50.591+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version 
v3.2.14
2017-06-25T14:53:50.591+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 
92f6668a768ebf294bd4f494c50f48459198e6a3
2017-06-25T14:53:50.591+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL 
version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-06-25T14:53:50.591+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: 
tcmalloc
2017-06-25T14:53:50.591+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-06-25T14:53:50.591+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build 
environment:
2017-06-25T14:53:50.591+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 
ubuntu1604
2017-06-25T14:53:50.591+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: 
x86_64
2017-06-25T14:53:50.591+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     
target_arch: x86_64
2017-06-25T14:53:50.591+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-06-25T14:53:50.609+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): 
bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 
0.0.0.0:27017
2017-06-25T14:53:50.609+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already 
in use
2017-06-25T14:53:50.609+0530 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set 
up sockets during startup.
2017-06-25T14:53:50.609+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 
48
```

And on issuing a `sudo netstat -plnt` I get the following output,

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address  
State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               
LISTEN      1920/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6942          0.0.0.0:*               
LISTEN      3725/java         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               
LISTEN      7272/mongod     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*               
LISTEN      
3725/java
```

Thank you in advance!! I appreciate all the help!!

Comment: Most simple explanation is the server is already running. For some reason you are trying to start another instance. Perhaps you should choose another port if you really mean to run another instance.

Comment: Thank you for replying!! I am actually learning MongoDB as I am learning to develop my first web app using the MEAN stack. And so, pardon me if I am wrong. But how can I stop the server in this case? And, if that's not possible how can I reach the instance thats already running?

Comment: I get the following message on issuing a `mongod --shutdown` 
There doesn't seem to be a server running with dbpath: /data/db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly tells the problem. You are trying to start a process that is already running or assign it to a port which is occupied. There are few ways to solve this.

**1. Stop the service and start it again**

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo mongod
```

**2. Quick fix** ( may not be the best according to their documentations)

```
killall mongod
```

**3. Deal with the process**
Fins out which process is running the mongodb port

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :27017
```

Next, kill the process that is using it by the command

```
sudo kill PID
```

(PID - Process id)

Now, you can start it again. It should be up and running!

Comment: Option 1 worked.! I am surprised, I had tried this before and despite of that I kept getting the same messages. Anyways, I am getting another error now. However, I am moving ahead. :D Thank you very much!!

Comment: @bhagyashree khairnar I am glad you found it useful.